# gpxlogger not reading any data unless cgps runs

Tags: gps

I have the GPS daemon running as user gpsd:

```
/usr/sbin/gpsd -N /dev/ttyUSB0 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

I have gpxlogger running as root:

```
gpxlogger -d -f /data/%Y%m%d-%H%M%S.gpx
```

Initially, all what gpxlogger writes is the gpx preamble, but no actual fixes.

gpxlogger starts to log actual fixes, as soon as I run another gpsd client like 'cgps -d' or 'gpsmon'.
When this other gpsd client ends, gpxlogger stops to log fixes after some time.

It appears as if gpxlogger is not a "sufficient" client "to make" gpsd provide actual fixes.

For now my workaround is to autostart "cgps -s" in a terminal.

Comment: For now my workaround is to autostart "cgps -s" in a terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another closer look into the [gpxlogger's manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/gpsd-clients/gpxlogger.1.en.html) revealed to use the `-e <export-method>` with `-l` listing all available export methods. So now I invoke gpxlogger this way and it gets the fixes without another gpsd client running:

```
gpxlogger -e sockets -d -f /data/%Y%m%d-%H%M%S.gpx
```

Comment: As you've found your own answer you can accept your own answer as the answer.